# Kendo Grid pagination button shows in vertical format

Tags: angularjs, rest, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid in my application and I am binding data to it through REST call. When the grid load first time, the buttons doesn't show up. Below is the example:

[image]

There are 400+ items in the grid, currently it is configured to show only 50 items per page. But the problem is I am not able to see options to visit second/next page.

Option of second page is visible when I change items per page. Like If I change option from 50 - 100. I am able to see other page number.

This is the second Problem. Page number appears in vertical way instead of horizontal.

[image]

I need help in solving below issues:

1. When Page Load pagination options should be displayed as they are suppose to be.
2. Pagination numbers should appear in horizontal way not in vertical way.

Below is my code snippet:

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = {
        editable: true,
        pageable: {
            pageSizes: [15,25,50,100]
        },
        navigatable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            pageSize: 50,
            batch: false,
            requestEnd: function(e) {
                if (e.type != 'read')
                {
                    $('#grdItemizations').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();  
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { type: "number", editable: false },
                                         Title: { type: "string",editable: false }
                    }
                },
                data: function (data) {
                    return data.d && data.d.results ? data.d.results : [];
                }
            },
            transport: {
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if (type != "read") {
                        var strIfy = kendo.stringify({
                            "__metadata": type != "create" ? { "type": },
                            "Title": data.Title,
                            "Id": type != "create" ? data.ID : undefined
                        });
                        return strIfy;
                    }
                    return kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap.apply(this, arguments);
                },
                read: {
                },
                update: {

                },
                create: {
                },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
    }           
            },    
        },
        columns: [ 
            { field: "Id", title: "ID" , width: "60px"},
            { field: "Title", title: "Analytic Inventory Description" , width: "220px"}
        ]
    }
```

Any hint, help is really appreciated.

Comment: also double check if you are injecting correct data to grid. problem can be in binding to incoming json

Answer (score 0):

There can be other issues since you have not posted complete code.

First of all , I suspected there was was **something off(missing css,incorrect version of kendo css referred, murtiple css conflicting) on css side** since that deals with the presentation of grid .

Then i pulled up a  [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IYulO/2) and removed these css files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" />
```

and see the image below surprisingly the result are kind of little similar i can see pagination button in a vertical format.

Please double check something is off on css side(check reference to kendo grid css by looking at viewsource page) if that does not solve problem make sure you post the complete code

[image]

Comment: Actually there are two grid on same page. 
One grid is working perfectly fine and another is giving me problem. If there was CSS issue then both grid should have failed.

Comment: post the complete code here - some thing is conflicting